# Any recommentations for self-service advertisement hosting?

Tags: ads

I would like a advertisement hosting that does the following:
1. allow publisher to place ads themselves.
2. allow customers of the publisher to place ads themselves, i.e. self-service.

Google Ads Manager (Double-Click) and OpenX don't do #2.
At this moment, I have only found one that did: trafficspaces.com.

I would like to evaluate more.

Any recommendations?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Project Wonderful:
http://www.projectwonderful.com/

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't allow self-service that is restricted to my website only.